# Adding a variable to opacity in a loop using Less

Tags: css, loops, less, opacity

I have a loop in Less which contains `opacity`. I would like the `opacity` to change based on the loop number variable but I keep getting an error "unrecognised input".

Something like this...

```
div {
    .circles(5);

    .circles(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
        &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
            opacity: 0.@{i};
        }
        .circles(@n, (@i + 1));
    }
}
```

I've tried this too...

```
opacity: 0.@i;
```

and I've tried adding quotes in various places.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For printing out numbers, you would be better off using mathematical operations (like multiplication in this case) than using string concatenation. The below snippet should produce the output that you are looking for:

```
div {
  .circles(5);
  .circles(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
      opacity: 0.1*@i; /* multiplication by 0.1 automatically converts it to number */
    }
    .circles(@n, (@i + 1));
  }
}
```

---

**Strictly don't do:** (Explanation is only for understanding)

Coming to the code in question, you are trying to append the value of a variable to a String (`0.`) and for that you need to enclose the whole thing within quotes like in below snippet. String concatenation would happen only when this syntax is followed. One extra thing to note is that the output value that is printed should not have the quotes character and hence `~` or `e()` should be used to strip out the quotes.

```
div {
  .circles(5);
  .circles(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
      opacity: ~"0.@{i}";
    }
    .circles(@n, (@i + 1));
  }
}
```